# apache24 won't run cgi scripts

Tags: apache, perl

`httpd-error.log`:

```
[Sat Jul 18 17:30:22.505894 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 30498] [client 24.224.147.251:40394] AH01215: env: perl: No such file or directory: /srv/http/forum.fgfugees.ca/htdocs/cgi-bin/test.cgi

[Sat Jul 18 17:30:22.505987 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 30498] [client 24.224.147.251:40394] End of script output before headers: test.cgi
```

that file does exist, i can successfully run it by typing

```
/usr/bin/env perl /srv/http/forum.fgfugees.ca/htdocs/cgi-bin/test.cgi
```

into my CLI.

httpd.conf: http://pastebin.com/MGGFNcyQ

i'm testing the script under the forum.fgfugees.ca virtual host, which begins at line 287

the script is located at: /srv/http/forum.fgfugees.ca/htdocs/cgi-bin/

test.cgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "sup bitch";
```

Comment: Where is test.cgi script?

Comment: the script is located at: /srv/http/forum.fgfugees.ca/htdocs/cgi-bin/

Comment: I meant to share `test.cgi` it in question. Anyways modify the shebang line to `#!/usr/bin/env perl`. Then check once.

Comment: check the new edit for the file source

Comment: what is output of `ls -la /usr/bin/perl` and `ls -la /srv/http/forum.fgfugees.ca/htdocs/cgi-bin/test.cgi`

Comment: # ls -la /usr/bin/perl
ls: /usr/bin/perl: No such file or directory
# ls -la /srv/http/forum.fgfugees.ca/htdocs/cgi-bin/test.cgi
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www  www  77 Jul 18 17:13 /srv/http/forum.fgfugees.ca/htdocs/cgi-bin/test.cgi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83628/discussion-between-arunesh-singh-and-cracksmoker9000).

Answer (score 1):

In your shell's login script, you alter PATH, allowing `perl` to be located from your shell. But only from your shell. Replace

```
/usr/bin/env perl
```

in the shebang line with the actual path to your `perl`.

```
type -p perl
```

or

```
which perl
```

may help you determine what that path is.

Answer (score 0):

Apache couldn't run /usr/bin/env perl for some reason.

Some sort of permission error that I bypassed by using the shebang line `#!/usr/local/bin/perl` instead